How exe and dll were actual loading in Windows?
Can anyone point me some document explains how exactly Windows processes loads-starts and how Windows loads dlls at start of process?
Step by step - which system functions were called, what actions were done.

This question is far too broad and theoretical for this site. On our programming sister site a very similar question was asked several years ago that had a lot of self-effort on the part of the asker, and received what appear to be some pretty good answers. Please read that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61225271/fully-understanding-how-exe-file-is-executed

The Windows Internals books will help you out in terms of gaining an understanding of the under-the-hood mechanics of Windows.  Pluralsight also has a good Windows Internals course taught by Pavel Yosifovich.
As a side note, I think that this question is appropriate for superuser because it's asking for documentation, not necessarily insight into source code.  Knowledge of Windows Internals is beneficial for programmers and troubleshooters.

Thanks for the comments. It's gross that such fundamental questions counts as " become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers". I have read some issues of Windows Internals, but exactly this question is not deeply revealed (also present info is scattered among various chapters). Tried to find some more but get a not very much info.
